# How Can I Save A Value From Runnables In Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences, runnable

```
lateinit var sharedPreferences : SharedPreferences
var number = 0
var runnable : Runnable = Runnable{ }
var handler : Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.runnables", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val recordFromSP = sharedPreferences.getInt("record",-1)
    textView2.text = "Last Time Record: $recordFromSP"

}


fun start(view:View){
        number = 0
        runnable = object : Runnable{
            override fun run() {
                number = number+1
                textView.text = "Time: $number"
                button3.setEnabled(false)
                button4.setEnabled(true)
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000)
                var record = number

            }
        }
        handler.post(runnable)
}

fun stop(view:View){

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    number = 0
    textView.text = "Time: 0"
    Toast.makeText(this,"Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    button4.setEnabled(false)
    button3.setEnabled(true)
    ***sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("record",record)***

}
```

How can I get the last value from the timer(from runnable in start() function)
I can't reach the record value from anywhere outside runnable function of course.
So it gives an error in "sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("record",**record**)"
How can I take the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it in such a way since the `var record` is a local variable of another method inside another anonymous class.
So you need to declare the `var record` as a variable of your main Activity class (where you already have `var number` and others).

Answer (score 0):

You need something in scope that's accessible from both `start` and `stop` functions.

I would suggest declaring `record` in the enclosing class/file
maybe like a `private lateinit var`.

Then you can check if it is initialized (aka it ran at least once)
before accessing it.

Or you could make it a plain `var` initialized to a default value if you don't care about that.

```kotlin
private lateinit var record: Int

fun start() {
    number = 0
    runnable = object : Runnable{
        override fun run() {
            number = number+1
            textView.text = "Time: $number"
            button3.setEnabled(false)
            button4.setEnabled(true)
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000)
            record = number // here it is assigned
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
}

fun stop(view:View){

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    number = 0
    textView.text = "Time: 0"
    Toast.makeText(this,"Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    button4.setEnabled(false)
    button3.setEnabled(true)
// TODO: use if(this::record.isInitialized) to prevent exceptions
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("record",record)

}
```

Comment: To prevent exceptions it's better to not use lateinit. It's enough just init is as 0 or null, depends on purpose of the variable.

Comment: @sergpetrov `lateinit` only throws exceptions if you don't initialise it before you read from it, which means there's an error in your code. If you can't guarantee it will be initialised before it's accessed, then that's a good use case for making it *nullable* - but don't go making stuff nullable that doesn't need to be, then you're just fighting with the null-safety system and giving yourself all the problems `lateinit` is designed to avoid. It's extremely useful! You can't make primitives like `Int` `lateinit` though

Comment: @cactustictacs I know `lateinit` but it should be used mostly with attention and in specific cases. In this case, we can't guarantee that the variable will be initialized before using it and because of that, the developer has to remember the checking `if(this::record.isInitialized)` everywhere where he will want to use it. It's quite inconvinient and easy to forget.

Comment: @sergpetrov if you can guarantee `start` will be called before `stop` then you can definitely guarantee `record` will be initialised before it's read! If you have to use `isInitialized` then that's usually a sign that you can't guarantee the order of things, and you should be making it *nullable* instead (since "no value" is a valid and possible state, and then the null-checking system forces you to handle it safely). But that's usually for situations like async code execution - generally you should be able to say what order things happen in, and if you can, then `lateinit` is often useful

Comment: I'm really pointing this out because people avoiding `lateinit` and using `null` instead often leads to things like flooding their code with `!!` or using non-null versions of their nullable field like `val someProperty get() = _someProperty!!`, just to get around the null-checking requirement they've created for themselves, and they believe isn't necessary. If you can guarantee a variable initialised as *null* isn't *null* anymore, then that's exactly the same thing as guaranteeing a `lateinit` property has been set to something, y'know? It's just messier and leads to bad habits

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution here is to just store `number` (which is what `record` is set to) before you clear it:

```
// can't access 'record' from outside the runnable (or even outside the 'run' function),
// but it's the same value as 'number', which you can read!
var record = number
```

```
fun stop(view:View){
    // immediately stop any more updates from happening
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    // the runnable has been incrementing 'number' (and referring to it as 'record'),
    // so we just need to store whatever value that's reached
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("record", number)

    // now we've stored it, we can clean up and reset everything
    number = 0
    textView.text = "Time: 0"
    Toast.makeText(this,"Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    button4.setEnabled(false)
    button3.setEnabled(true)
}
```

---

As a more general case, when you're declaring anonymous objects, then any properties you add to them (like a top-level `record` property, as opposed to the local variable you were creating in `run()`) will only be visible inside the function that created it:

```
// storing the Runnable where everything can access it
lateinit var myRunnable: Runnable

fun start() {
    // creating a Runnable stored at the top level, with an extra property
    myRunnable = object : Runnable {
        // adding a public property
        var record = 0
        override fun run() { ... }
    }

    // you can access 'record' here because the object was declared in this function's
    // scope, so the compiler -knows- it has that 'record' property
    println(myRunnable.record)
}

fun stop() {
    // you can't do this here, because this function only knows 'myRunnable's -declared type-.
    // It doesn't know it has a 'record' property, only that it has a 'run()' function
    // (since it's a Runnable)
    println(myRunnable.record)
}
```

So you'll have to create an actual `class` with that property defined on it, so that everything interacting with that object knows about `record`:

```
abstract class RecordRunnable : Runnable {
    abstract var record: Int
}

lateinit var myRunnable: RecordRunnable

fun start() {
    // creating a Runnable stored at the top level, with an extra property
    myRunnable = object : RecordRunnable() {
        // override since it's a property declared on the type
        override var record = 0
        override fun run() { ... }
    }
}

fun stop() {
    // now this works because 'record' is a property on the declared type, RecordRunnable
    println(myRunnable.record)
}
```

You could also create a single top-level `object` declaration instead of creating a `class` (if you want to reuse the same singleton `Runnable` instead of creating new instances of it). You can read more about this stuff [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html)!